# Ansible - loop on an array result from a shell command

Tags: mysql, shell, ansible

I am starting to learn Ansible and I have something wanted to be done.

I have this snippet of code below where I am trying to grep a file and output the results on a variable in Ansible, then use that result (array) to loop to another command like this code below:

```
- hosts: dbserver
  remote_user: root
  gather_facts: false
  vars_files:
  - vars.yaml
  - name: table_list put to array
    action: shell cat /usr/tables/table_list | grep -v "^center"
    register: tables
  - name: create tables
    command: mysql -u {{ mysql.username }} --password={{ mysql.password }} -D sys3 < /usr/tables/create.{{ item }}.sql
    with_items:
    - "{{ tables }}"
```

I can't seem to find out how this should be done. I checked stackoverflow to any related but I failed to see one that is the same. Please guide me on this one. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of the `table_list put to array` task is an object and not the output directly. You can see the `debug` module to see its contents:

```
- debug: var=tables
```

Reference: [Ansible documentation on debug](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/debug_module.html)

Given that your `grep` command works correctly, you should be able to access the contents of the output from `tables.stdout_lines` and not `tables` directly.

Also take a look at [Registering Variables](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#registered-variables).

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply. I got it working using `with_items: tables.stdout_lines` ... I tried this one a while ago but I don't know why I got something wrong, but after reading your answer, like charm! Thanks!